# In Groovy, what is the precedence of the membership operator ("in")

Tags: groovy

http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_operator_precedence does not list the  "in" (membership) binary operator. What is its precedence?

Comment: The in operator is now in the documentation.  The new operator binds very tightly, so no extra parentheses are needed around new File(path).canonicalPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the source code of the Groovy parser itself: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/antlr/groovy.g#L2337:

```
(  7)  < <= > >= instanceof as in
```

So, the "in" operator has the same precedence as "instanceof", "as", etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found in the groovy documentation

http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_operator_precedence

Comment: No, it's missing. This documentation defines precedence 7 for operators `<` `<=` `>` `>=` `instanceof` `as`, but not for `in`...